# Collision bit reaches its maximum value while Initialization in LIBGDX

Tags: libgdx, collision-detection, short

I am using Category_bits for detecting collision in LIBGDX. I have used all the values ranging from 0 to 16384 . Since we have to use the power of 2 while initializing the values, I have exceeded the limit and I am not able to initialize any bits anymore. The range for short_ bit is 0 to 16384 and if I use the next multiple of that number, after type casting it to a short value, the Category_bits doesn't detect collision between objects. Nothing happens when the object collides when I set the value greater than 16384.

Here is how I initialize the values,

```
    public static final short x = 0;
    public static final short y = 1; 
    public static final short z = 2;
    public static final short a = 4;
    public static final short b = 8;
    public static final short c = 16;
           .....
    public static final short d = 16384;
     public static final short e = (short) 32768; // exceeded the limit so type casted the number to short
```

When I type cast and use it, nothing collision detection happens. I have to detect collision in many things in my game so I need the solution to get rid of this problem. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise re-checking over your code and decide whether you actually *need* that many different categories. Even if you have that many different types of objects I suspect you could group together those which have the same collision filters into just one bit, you can then use other ways of identifying which "type" of entity is involved in a collision.

If you do really need to use that many different objects then the Box2d `World` class has a method `setContactFilter(ContactFilter filter)` which will allow you to specify a custom [ContactFilter](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/ContactFilter.html). This contains a `shouldCollide(Fixture a, Fixture b)` which returns true if `a` and `b` should collide and vice versa.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how to use grouping in box 2d collision ? Because there is not much tutorials for that !! I followed this blog http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/2011/07/box2d-tutorial-collision-filtering/ and I got confused of why we must asign a negative value to collision bit ? @Basim Khajwal

Answer (score -1):

short also worked for me with minus numbers, because it reaches from -32768 till 32767 so you can also use
-32678, -16384 and so on.

I don't know how to use the contact filters, but I work with UserData which also works pretty good for me.

when you create your body I wrote something like this:

```
b2body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("something");
```

and in my collision detection I used something like this:

```
public class WorldContactListener implements ContactListener{

    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        Fixture fixA = contact.getFixtureA();
        Fixture fixB = contact.getFixtureB();

        int cdef = fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits | fixB.getFilterData().categoryBits;

switch(cdef) {

case BreedingSeason.HERO_BIT | BreedingSeason.TRAMPOLIN_BIT:
            if(fixA.getUserData() == "somethingElse" && fixB.getUserData() == "something") {
                ...
            } else if(fixB.getUserData() == "somethingElse" && fixA.getUserData() == "something") {
                ...
            }  
            break;
}
```

and don't forget the break after each case in the switch ;)

i hope this helps you

Comment: but don't use 32767, i can't explain why, but it doesn't worked for me